# No table is open in the current work area

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbf

While trying to create `CDX` file on existing `DBF` file using below code, I'm getting an exception saying "`No table is open in the current work area"`.

Language - `C#`

Exception Details -

```
Message - No table is open in the current work area.
Source - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro
```

Below is code snippet:

```
     public void CreateIndex()
    {
        var cdxExpressions = new List<CDXExpression> {
            new CDXExpression { expression = "ENTRY_DATE", name = "cdx_p1"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "ENTRY_CODE", name = "cdx_p2"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Month", name = "cdx_p3"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Year", name = "cdx_p4"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Company", name = "cdx_p5"}
        };

        string dbfFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBFFileLocation"];
        string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + dbfFile + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        var queries = DBFQuery.CreateCDXQueries(cdxExpressions, dbfFile);

        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            foreach (var qry in queries)
            {
                OleDbParameter script = new OleDbParameter("script", qry);
                OleDbCommand dbfCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                dbfCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dbfCommand.CommandText = "ExecScript";
                //dbfCommand.Connection.Open();
                dbfCommand.Parameters.Add(script);
                dbfCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // I should Open the DBF/Table in the current work area to avoid the exception
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

How to open DBF file in c# to avoid exception "No table is open in the current work area", also using `Microsoft OLE DB Provider` for `Visual FoxPro`

Comment: DBF File location in config file -
    <add key="DBFFileLocation" value="C:\DBF\DM1712.DBF"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is with your CDXExpression list:

```
public void CreateIndex()
{
    var cdxExpressions = new List<CDXExpression> {
            new CDXExpression { expression = "ENTRY_DATE", name = "cdx_p1"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "ENTRY_CODE", name = "cdx_p2"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Month", name = "cdx_p3"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Year", name = "cdx_p4"},
            new CDXExpression { expression = "Company", name = "cdx_p5"}
        };

    var myCode = "use sample exclusive\n" +
          string.Join("\n", cdxExpressions.Select(e => $"index on {e.expression} tag {e.name}")) +
          "\nuse";

    string dbfFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBFFileLocation"];
    string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + dbfFile;

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "ExecScript";
        OleDbParameter parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
        parm.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
        parm.Value = myCode;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding the most important part, the code of CreateCDXQueries. Somewhere before attempting to create the index you should have opened the table in the current work area as exclusive. Also, remove that Extended Properties part from connection string.
Here is a very basic example. Suppose you have already have a table created with this command (or create within the same Execscript call):

```
Create Table ('d:\temp\IndexTest') free (id int, firstName c(10), lastName c(10))
```

This is C# code to create index tags:

```
static void Main()
{
    string myCode =
    @"use indexTest exclusive
index on firstName tag firstName
index on lastName tag LastName
index on id tag id
use
";

    string strCon = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=d:\temp";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "ExecScript";
    OleDbParameter parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
    parm.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

    parm.Value = myCode;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

There is no try...catch in code as it was a quick sample.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ceting Basoz.                                           My Requirement here limits to create CDX on existing DBF file, thus can't include Create as part of query. I tried below code, executes fine with No CDX file generation.   Script Syntax -         USE SAMPLE.DBF IN SELECT(0) EXCLUSIVE INDEX ON ENTRY_DATE  ASCENDING  TAG cdx_p1.

Comment: `foreach (var qry in queries)
 {
 OleDbParameter script = new OleDbParameter("script", @"USE 
           SAMPLE.DBF IN SELECT(0) EXCLUSIVE " + qry);
OleDbCommand dbfCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
dbfCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dbfCommand.CommandText = "ExecScript";
OleDbParameter parm = dbfCommand.CreateParameter();
 parm.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
dbfCommand.Parameters.Add(parm);
 }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { // I should Open the DBF/Table in the current work area to avoid the exception
 }`

Comment: While your code is not the one that should be used, it would work. So is it solved? Why would you ever have "in select(0)" there? If you do that, and suppose current area was in use, that table would be used in another work area and you would indexing some other table (or get error attempting to do that). If you really need  to use in Select(0) then first have "Select 0" as the first line.

Comment: Hmm seeing your second script it is getting worse. Wish you did it like I showed. Gimme a few minutes and I will give you a script for your tags (I don't know what your queries return).