# Visual FoxPro DB - Create/Update/Drop table using ODBC

Tags: odbc, foxpro

I am able to use the ODBC drivers (Microsoft's and other providers) with Visual FoxPro Database. I am able to execute Select & Insert statements using the ODBC Drivers but not able to use Create/Update/Drop table using the ODBC Drivers.
I am able to create a table using Visual FoxPro IDE but would like to do it using ODBC Driver.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The CREATE command is not supported in the ODBC driver but UPDATE and DROP should be - it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing any code.#

Answer (score 0):

VFP doesn't have an ODBC driver from MS since 6.x. Other than that you can use ExecScript to create\drop table. Check
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167359/no-table-is-open-in-the-current-work-area) for a sample.